# how can i update in mysql using 2 condition in where

Tags: mysql

Im having trouble updating table name

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table_name SET table = '$_POST[id]' WHERE room = '$_POST[room]','row[bed]'");
```

Comment: And that problem is...?

Comment: What is `row[bed]` supposed to be used for? You're not comparing it with anything.

Comment: You are trying to rename the table? I'm confused as to what you are trying to do. Update a field name called table-name?

Answer (score 2):

Lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerabilities, and lovely SQL syntax error....

You have zero error handling which would have alerted you to the syntax error:

```
... WHERE room = '$_POST[room]','row[bed]'")
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^--- illegal syntax
```

At bare minimum, you should have somethign like

```
$result = mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());
```

Never assume a query succeeds. ALWAYS check for a failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Answer (score 0):

Special words must be used within backtits

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table_name SET `table` = '$_POST[id]' WHERE room = '$_POST[room]','row[bed]'");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly your table and fields are, but you can try like below:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table_name SET table = '$_POST[id]' WHERE room = '$_POST[room]' and FieldName = 'row[bed]'");
```

OR

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table_name SET table = '$_POST[id]' WHERE room IN( '$_POST[room]','row[bed]')");
```